# Mac Eclipse Create Android - “Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project”

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My tools are:
eclipse indigo 3.7.2
adt 24.0.2
sdk 24.0.2
java 7.0.80

---

In xp and win7 it works well.

---

But in mac 10.9.3, it works with error:
1).I have installed java 6 before, in /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk,
and then install java 7 right now, in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.80.jdk.
(tips: Java 6 and java 7 are both exist. Run java -version, it show java 1.7.0.80.)
2).I have added the two lines before -vmargs in eclipse.ini
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.lib
(tips: I don't know why is "%java 7 home%/jre/lib/server/libjvm.lib" but not "%java 7 home%/bin/java".)
3).When I create Android, I got the following error message:

```
Errors occurred during the build.<br>
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'MyFirstApp'.<br>
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Please upgrade to Android Studio with Latest SDK. Official support for eclipse has been terminated by Google long ago and there are chances that your app might not even get approved by playstore if not switched to latest SDKs using Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks, but some times we are also need to use eclipse. I am interesting that it work well in xp and win7, but error in mac 10.9.3.

Comment: yes it works with work arounds, but what is the point of developing an app that will be rejected by play store.

Comment: Thanks again. We don't need to submit to play store.